# Grouping inputs generated by `inputs_form` in Phoenix Forms

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have following relationship in my project A has many B and C has many B thus B is in-between table.

When in rendering Phoenix.Form for record from table A i want to edit records from table B, but I want them to be grouped by data from record from table C.

Currently it is being rendered like this:

```
<%= inputs_for @d |> IO.inspect(), :record_a, fn f -> %>
  <div id="date">
    <div class="form-group row">
        #magic
    </div>
    <%= link "Remove", to: "#", id: "delete_date", class: "btn btn-danger" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

and I want to render all `record_a` with c_foreign key equal X in one "#date" div, all `record_b` with c_foreign_key equal Y in another and so forth, and so on.

What I've tried so far:

- Using many_to_many relation, but i did produce unwanted behaviour of retrieving duplicates. Consider a,b,c as unique records from table C, then relation returned list of [a, a, a, b, b, c] where count of duplicates would match count of in between records (which doesn't make sense for me since I was able to get in between data from any of the duplicates..)
- Using virtual field in ecto schema that contained map as base for rendering. This failed because inputs_for prompt to use only relation fields (like embed_many, has_many etc)

I think I may have basically misenderstood principles of phoenix forms :| I would rather not try to render that form manually (generating names is a bit tedious)

Comment: I am not 100% clear on your question, but I think you may need to manually generate the html in your form, then map that in a changeset to properly build the associations.
You may also need a different assign to build the inputs, depending on the way your join is structured...
I've recently done something similar and my experience has been that you basically have to manually pipe attrs through `cast_assoc` or `put_assoc`.

Comment: I am more conceirned about rendering part. I want to take advantage of goodies like select_date etc.